# ClassCast Exception

Tags: java, exception

I've written a method that has some casting errors:

```
public class Factor {
    public static int[] findFactors(ArrayList<Integer> nums){
        ArrayList<Integer> factors= new ArrayList();

        for(Integer i=new Integer(0);i<nums.size();i++) {

            System.out.println(nums.get(i));
            for(int j=0;j<nums.get(i);j++) {
                if (nums.get(i) %j==0) {
                    factors.add(j);
                }
            }
        }

        int ct=0;
        String factorString= factors.toString();
        char[] charArray= factorString.toCharArray();
        int[] factorArray= new int[(charArray.length+1)/2]; 

        for(int a=0;a<charArray.length;a++) {
            if(charArray[a]==',') {
                continue;
            } else { 
                String s= Character.toString(charArray[a]);
                factorArray[ct]=Integer.parseInt(s);
                ct++;
            }
        }
        return factorArray;
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean exception handling?

Comment: @user1843145.. Yeah. Post the stack trace of the exception you got.

Comment: This is my error: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @user1843145 Edit your question to add the full stack trace, and point out in your code which line it's thrown at.

Comment: Someone should make a compiler for one of those joke languages that, when it finds syntax errors, it just says "Your code won't work"

Comment: its at for(int j=0;j<nums.get(i);j++) {

Comment: @user1843145 maybe `int` and `Interger` are not the same thing?

Comment: ill test the code. Sorry I am a beginner in java

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have that you only escape the `,` but when you use `toString()` on a List it is enclose in square brackets `[]`. When you fix that you will discover that size of result array is not valid also you have to subtract 2 (the brackets).

Good Luck with rest. And please read some basic manual about Java.

Comment: I used toString()  on an array

Comment: Nope `factors.toString();`, if you used on array then you will have memory address. And you would not try to escape `,`

Comment: Oh, there were 2 uses of the toString() method, but the exception says:'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer'